# Iterate hashmap to get particular data

Tags: java, loops, iterator, hashmap, hashtable

I have a hashmap. I want to iterate hashmap to get only values as in hashmap, it contains so many key-value pair. Please guide me,how to get that. I cannot paste the code because of security issue.

Comment: Have you checked `HashMap` api?

Comment: How about you paste a code that is similar and only shows that part that you are struggling with?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should check the `java.util.Map` API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()

Answer (score 0):

Like @Smutje said, the `Map#values()` does exactly what you requested : it gives you a collection containning all the values of your Map.

However if, like you said, your Map containts so many entries you should probably check your design to make sure it's actually a good idea to iterate on all the values. When using a Map one except to access values by their keys, doing (frequent) iteration on the values, especially if there are many, looks like a smell to me.

Also, if you really want to iterate on your Map you may want to have a look a `LinkedHashMap` and `TreeMap`, which may be more appropriate for that (depending on your use case, of course).